# One Entity used in many, many-to-one relationships

Tags: php, doctrine, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have following entities:

```php
class File{
    private $fileId;
    
    private $filePath;
}

class User{
    private $userId;

    private array $userFiles;
}

class Order{
    private $orderId;
    
    private array $orderFiles;
}
```

I have three entities: `File`, `User`, `Order`.
Now I want to link `User` to `File` as one2many relationships. One user can have multiple files. And the same with `Order` - connect `Order` with `File` via one2many relationship - one order can have multiple files.

My question is, do I need to create two(one for relation with `User`, and one for relation with `Order`) tables for the `File` entity?

Or I can merge these two tables into one and for instance, add field `type` in `File` entity, which will tell us to which entity(`User`/`File`) it belongs.

Here you have my uncomplete mapping in xml

```xml
<entity name="File" table="file">
    <id name="fileId" type="uuid">
        <generator strategy="NONE" />
    </id>
    <field name="filePath />
</entity>

<entity name="User" table="user">
    <id name="userId" type="uuid">
        <generator strategy="NONE" />
    </id>
    <one-to-many field="userFiles" target-entity="File" mapped-by="herewhat?" >
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist />
        </cascade>
    </one-to-many>
</entity>

<entity name="Order" table="order">
    <id name="orderId" type="uuid">
        <generator strategy="NONE" />
    </id>
    <one-to-many field="orderFiles" target-entity="File" mapped-by="herewhat?" >
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist />
        </cascade>
    </one-to-many>
</entity>
```

I would prefer the second option - everything in one table if it is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to have two separate tables like order_files/user_files instead of stiffing everything in 1 table and relay on something like type(string) to get your collection afterwords. Also now this seems to be very simple table(files I mean), but with the time it can developed more and you may need different fields for the two different file types. So if you take this option you can build the relations b/n the tables as(for example the Order/orderFiles):

...

```
/**
 * @var Collection|OrderFiles[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PathToMyEntity\OrderFile", mappedBy="order")
 */
protected $orderFiles;
```

Then function you need add remove items in this collection, something like this:
....

```
/**
 * @param $orderFiles
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function addOrderFiles($orderFiles)
{
    $this->orderFiles = $orderFiles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param $orderFiles
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeOrderFiles($orderFiles)
{
    foreach ($orderFiles as $orderFile) {
        $this->orderFiles->removeElement($orderFile);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add orderFile
 *
 * @param OrderFile $orderFile
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function addOrderFile(OrderFile $orderFile)
{
    $this->orderFiles[] = $orderFile;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove orderFile
 *
 * @param OrderFile $orderFile
 */
public function removeOrderFile(OrderFile $orderFile)
{
    $this->orderFiles->removeElement($orderFile);
}

/**
 * Get orderFile
 *
 * @return Collection|OrderFile[]
 */
public function getOrderFiles()
{
    return $this->orderFiles;
}
```

....

Now lets manage this relation on the file class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PathToMyEntity\Order", inversedBy="orderFiles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $order;
```

And the get set methods:

```
/**
 * Get order
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return $this->order;
}

/**
 * Set order
 *
 * @param Order $order
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function setOrder(Order $order)
{
    $this->order = $order;

    return $this;
}
```

This is just a suggestion but it would be nice if some Doctrine guru gives opinion on this matter too :)

Comment: In a real situation, I would have to about 5 tables that will connect files with other Entities. 
And also if I have only one table, I can easily make one controller which will receive the id of the file, and based on the `type` will return the file.

Comment: but file tables will hold just link to the file? Why do you actually need it in first place?

Comment: The file table will hold information about the file, like uploaded_at, mimetype, size, etc.

Comment: well if 1 File entity is the option what you need than go for for it, you'll link it to the rest of the entities without nullable=false option :)